# Weka filter removeuseless issue

Tags: java, filter, weka

I am doing a classification with weka, I tried to use the filter.removeuseless, but with the same arff file, I found some differences betweeen using that in the code and in the GUI. In the code I invoked it in this way:

```
Normalize norm = new Normalize();
norm.setInputFormat(train);
Instances train_norm = Filter.useFilter(train, norm);

RemoveUseless ru = new RemoveUseless();
ru.setInputFormat(train_norm);
Instances train_new = Filter.useFilter(train_norm, ru);


Ranker rank = new Ranker();
InfoGainAttributeEval eval = new InfoGainAttributeEval();
eval.buildEvaluator(train_new);
```

The result is "strange" because the filter deleted a lot of attributes which the GUI kept as informative for the classification. (The filter in the GUI worked very well). What is the problem? Am I using it well in the code?

Answer (score 3):

i solved like this:

```
Normalize norm = new Normalize();
norm.setInputFormat(train);
train = Filter.useFilter(train, norm);

RemoveUseless ru = new RemoveUseless();
ru.setInputFormat(train);
train = Filter.useFilter(train, ru);

Ranker rank = new Ranker();
InfoGainAttributeEval eval = new InfoGainAttributeEval();
eval.buildEvaluator(train);
```